# How does Docker for Windows run Linux containers?

Tags: windows, docker, kernel

In the old versions of Docker for Windows, I remember it explicitly said it used a linux VM for the kernel.

But since the new stable version (released in July 2016 I think), it says

`Docker for Windows is a native Windows application with a native user interface and auto-update capability, deeply integrated with Windows native virtualization, Hyper-V, networking and file system`

If I understand correctly, the specified base image is for the user space and the host's kernel is used.
So, if I specify that I'm using an ubuntu base image to run the echo command, how does the Windows kernel come into play?

Or am I completely misunderstanding something?

Comment: This Docker for Windows runs only Windows containers

Comment: The beta can switch between Windows and Linux containers. It's not available in the stable release yet. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#/switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers-beta-feature

Comment: In that case, why am I able to run the `docker run ubuntu /bin/echo 'Hello world'` command with the latest stable?

Comment: I can point you to this presentation from one of the architect: [Linux Containers on Windows -- The Inside Story](https://dockercon.docker.com/watch/U7Bxp66uKmemZssjCTyXkm), John Starks, DockerCon Europe 2017.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Docker for Windows still uses a Linux VM to run Linux containers. But instead of using Virtual Box (which is what is used with Docker Toolbox), the Linux VM is run using Hyper-V - a Windows-native hypervisor. This means that Docker for Windows ships fewer components and has less moving parts.

If you install Docker for Windows and run `docker version` you'll see that the Docker Linux daemon is running on "Moby Linux".

Comment: As of DockerConf 2017, there were some new announcements about leveraging Windows 10's capabilities to host a Linux subsystem, so you may not need the full Docker for Windows' Linux VM running in HyperV