# Docker containers exit code 132

Tags: docker

docker worked properly as usual with existing containers on my computer (like kafka, mysql, postgres). Than I wanted to download new version of postgres and `docker run` command always shows `exit code 132`.

Doesn't matter which container I want to start all of it is an immediate exit with `132`
I checked `docker events`, `docker logs` but everything is empty.

Simple containers like `hello-world` can be started properly.

I found an article which mention sse4_2, but it's supported by CPU.
As far as I remember there was no system update since it worked.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Does your CPU support AVX instruction set? [For your reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403464/installing-superset-superset-db-upgrade-exit-with-code-132)

Comment: Also had exit code 132 for missing AVX2 on CPU, exit code seems linked to illegal opcode signal.

Comment: If your docker host is RHEL 7 then you have to use podman instead of docker commands.Else use other linux flavour like ubuntu as your docker host.More info https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1795574

Comment: did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: Exactly my issue with mongo:6.0.2 ... you can see it in docker log output if you check the exited container.

Answer (score 8):

**Step 1:**
Check if your CPU supports `amd64-avx`:
`$ sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep avx`
if it supports avx, it should high light `avx` but if not, it will return empty.

**Step 2:**
To solve the problem, run an image built to support `amd64` and not `amd64-avx` this may mean you have to run an earlier version.

A good example of this is the mongodb docker images, the latest version supports `amd64-avx` and will refuse to run on CPUs that don't support avx and exist with error code 132.

But when you run version 4.4 of mongodb,it runs without any issue.

For more information on this:
[Docker and -march native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657145/docker-and-march-native)

Comment: indeed, even if you run that inside a docker container you get an error in the logs telling you about that

Comment: For future visitors: I was running in Docker Desktop for Mac with the "Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon" turned on. The container in question didn't like that, once I turned it off it all worked.

Annoying some other containers core dump without it, so...damned if you do, damned if you don't!