# What is the cause of 'superset db upgrade' exiting with code 132 due CACHE_TYPE set to null?

Tags: apache-superset

I try to install superset on Fedora 31, I've followed the official document [site](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#python-virtualenv).

I have this error when I execute `superset db upgrade`

> - logging was configured successfully
> - INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
>   /home/mos/Workspace/superset/venv37/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask_caching/**init**.py:189:
>   UserWarning: Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, caching is
>   effectively disabled.
> - "Flask-Caching: CACHE_TYPE is set to null, "
> - Illegal instruction (core dumped)

with exit code 132

Comment: I encounter same issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out. It caused by the absence of AVX(Advanced Vector Extensions) support in the CPU.

Comment: can you tell me more about it? how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @martian_rover presumably use a CPU that has AVX support.