# Docker windows and linux

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Docker in my system tray has a menu item *Switch to Linux/Windows containers*.

Which should it be?

I don't *need* Windows because I'm writing .NET Core and using SQL Server Express.

How do I know if a Docker that I want to use (e.g., `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-nanoserver-1903` or `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1` or `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`) is Linux or Windows?

Comment: This is a duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556921/10327189

Comment: So I can use either Linux or Windows. How do I pick? Gut feeling is Linux because I don't _need_ the Windows API. But I'd like to have a better reason than _arbitrary guess_.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the images will be documented for which OS they are targeting on docker hub or in their documentation. For example [`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) targets Linux so you'll need to run a Linux Containers environment (scroll to the Full Tag Listing section).

---

For a more programmatic solution you are able to inspect images to learn more about them from your shell if you've previously pulled them. For example if I inspect an IIS image like `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019` we can see that it is built for Windows on amd64 cpu's.

You can inspect an image using `docker image inspect` from the command line.

```
docker image inspect mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019
```

The results will be a large json blob describing the images you inspected:

```
[
  {
    ...I've left out a lot of other details here
    "Architecture": "amd64",
    "OS": "windows",
    "OsVersion": "10.0.17763.973",
    ...
  }
]
```

For an answer of what type of containers you should be running you'll want to look at the "OS" value - in my example that's "windows" so we'll need Windows Containers support and get an error if we try to deploy the container into a linux environment.

To simplify this command and prevent you having to dig through a json file you can include a [`--format` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#get-a-subsection-in-json-format). For example:

```
docker image inspect mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019 --format='{{json .Os}}'
```

In my example I included "OSVersion" as well, this is particularly important when considering compatibility of Windows containers with the host version of Windows. You can learn more about [Windows Container Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility) in the docs. This value is less important for linux based containers and may not be present in all images.