# Why does this program runs in a container but not on the host?

Tags: c++, windows, docker, ubuntu, g++

I am doing a very simple docker image with a c++ written program that says hello.

I had to build the executable from a virtual machine, Ubuntu 18.04, x86-64.

I launched this executable on another machine, a Windows 10 64 bits via cmd, but it throws the following:

> hello.exe n’est pas compatible avec la version de Windows actuellement
> exécutée. Vérifiez dans les informations système de votre ordinateur,
> puis contactez l’éditeur de logiciel.

(says it's not compatible with this windows version)

When launching it with git bash, it throws:

> bash: ./hello.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I was expecting this executable not to be runable from within a container, as per my understanding, it shares the host libraries. But surprisingly, it does work:

```
$ docker run hello
Hello! This message is coming from a container
```

I would like to know why it is working fine. I must have misunderstood something somewhere.

The dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
ADD hello.exe /
CMD ["/hello.exe"]
```

The c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello! This message is coming from a container \n ";
    return 0;
}
```

g++ command used to build the executable:

```
g++ -o hello.exe -static main.cpp
```

Comment: You can't run Linux executables under Windows (and vice versa).

Comment: @molbdnilo, woops, indeed. But why is the program able to run inside the container which is on a windows host then ?

Comment: Because it's a Linux container?

Comment: Are you by any chance using WSL2 backend to host the Docker runtime on Windows? And just because you name the output `.exe` does not mean it is really a Windows executable file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile uses "scratch" image, which is a minimal (with very basic binaries to reduce the size).

> According to Docker Hub, the scratch image is Docker’s reserved empty
> image, which is useful in the context of building base images (such as
> debian and busybox) or super minimal images. As of Docker 1.5.0, FROM
> scratch is a no-op in the Dockerfile, and will not create an extra
> layer in our image. The FROM scratch command signals to the build
> process that we want the next command in the Dockerfile to be the
> first filesystem layer in our image.

```
FROM scratch
ADD hello.exe /
CMD ["/hello.exe"]
```

Scratch is a reserved empty linux image and can run linux binaries. Since,  you complied your program  on ubuntu, it can run on a linux container and  not on  your windows machine.

As other users, changing the extension to .exe does not make it a windows executable.

Good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556921/2777988

Further Reference: https://codeburst.io/docker-from-scratch-2a84552470c8

Comment: Just a quick question then: how is a linux image able to use a host windows ? Is this possible thanks to docker engine ? Where can I find a source explaining how the engine allows containers to use host resources ? It seems kile I am not able to use the correct keywords on google to find that information.

Comment: This will help clear some doubts https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556921/2777988